# What should be the data structure to store the big date OHLCV (exchange example)?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, binance

Exchangers, sites like TradingView.com, etc. Quickly response data for different intervals 15m, 30m, 1h, 4h and more. I have 2 questions about working with data:

1. They generate large timeframes on the fly using smaller ones or store all intervals in DB?
2. Recommend the best data structure for NOSQL to store OHLCV data for high performance and data manipulation.

**Example structure:**

```
{
    symbol: "BTCUSDT",
    data: [{
            ts: 1,
            o: 1,
            h: 2,
            l: 0.5,
            c: 1.5
        },
    ]
}
```

What can I try next?